# Concatenate character vectors in R where some elements have 0 characters

Tags: r, string, character, concatenation, paste

I have character vectors, where some elements have 0 characters. I want to concatenate them, but ignoring these 0 elements:

```
x <- c("a", "b", "", "d", "", "f")
y <- c("a", "", "c", "", "e", "f")
z <- c("a", "", "c", "d", "", "f")

paste(x, y, z, sep = ":")
# This gives:
# [1] "a:a:a" "b::"   ":c:c"  "d::d"  ":e:"   "f:f:f"

# But I want this:

# "a:a:a" "b"   "c:c"  "d:d"  "e"   "f:f:f"
```

EDIT: The above was a simplified example, this is a better approximation (I'm concatenating comments to single field)

```
x <- c("alpah beta", "better", "", "delta", "")
y <- c("alpha", "", "c", "", "fox, one")
z <- c("alpha", "", "can of worms", "delta", "")

paste(x, y, z, sep = "; ")
# Gives:
# "alpha beta; alpha; alpha" "better; ; " "; c; can of worms" "delta; ; delta" "; fox, one; "

# required
# "alpha beta; alpha; alpha"  "better"  "c; can of worms"  "delta; delta"  "fox, one"
```

I'd also be interested in a solution that works where the "" are replaced with NAs, but gives the same result.

Comment: Could post-process the output to remove :: or : from start or end of string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `paste0` them together which will ignore the blanks, then `strsplit` each character and `paste` them back together, collapsing with `:`.

```
sapply(strsplit(paste0(x,y,z),""),paste,collapse=":")
[1] "a:a:a" "b"     "c:c"   "d:d"   "e"     "f:f:f"
```

**Updated example**

Another approach is to use `Reduce` and a custom function to check for the blank elements:

```
Reduce(function (x,y) ifelse(x==""|y=="",paste0(x,y),paste(x,y,sep=":")),list(x,y,z))
[1] "alpah beta:alpha:alpha" "better"                 "c:can of worms"        
[4] "delta:delta"            "fox, one"
```

Comment: Thanks, I simplified the example, but when the character vectors have words or sentences in them, this won't work. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @CCID I've added another approach which will work for the new example

Answer (score 4):

Here is an option using `gsub`

```
gsub("^:+|:+$|:(?=:)", "", paste(x, y, z, sep = ":"), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "a:a:a" "b"     "c:c"   "d:d"   "e"     "f:f:f"
```

#### Update

The above code should also work for the updated example (as the OP changed the delimiter, we are also changing it)

```
gsub("^; |; $|; (?=;)", "", paste(x, y, z, sep = "; "), perl = TRUE)
#[1] "alpah beta; alpha; alpha" "better"                  
#[3] "c; can of worms"          "delta; delta"            
#[5] "fox, one"
```

NOTE: The OP's input string in 'x' is `alpah`.